# how to track rotation?

Tags: tracking

I am in was working on a project to track a boot model to live-action footage however when I try to track the rotation it is not accurate and it wobbles all around the place. 
one idea I had to track rotation was to find the different angle of two location tracks and then to use that to then track the rotation.
[image]

How would I do this, and is there another way?

Comment: How are you currently tracking the postition and rotation from the live-footage?

Comment: with an X mark then positioning a tracker in the center

Comment: Tracking rotation is very easily done using the tracking capabilities of the Movie Clip Editor. You can use one or many trackers. Then you can apply the rotation information on the compositor, or you can solve as object or use the trackers as empties inside the 3d environment. All it takes is to track the object carefully and not let the trackers slip See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out how to do this for me, instead of tracking rotation with the trackers, I did it manually by creating and x in the 3d world than making it to the boots X then parented it to the boot, this worked for me but was time-consuming
[image]

I may also try to color them in the real world as a reference for the 3d object tracker.

Comment: I may try to do the same with a 3d line at the top of the boot and manually track that to line up with the top of the boot as well.